# Isset value passing from URL not work in Google Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, html

It is work well when i use Firefox, but when i use Google Chrome, it is nothing happen.

**Here is my code:**

```
<script>
twttr.events.bind("tweet", function(event) {    
document.location.href =("?q="+event.target.parentNode.getAttribute("id")); 
});     
</script>
```

**//Here is the code to isset**

```
if(isset($_GET["q"])){

//some code

}
```

Does my code error?

Thank in advance.

Comment: did you try to `console.debug(event);` inside your callback to check what contain the event object ? It seems that `event.target.id` should work

Comment: I don't understand so far about what you told me. Can you detail about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check some more thing like Internet Explorer have output is html and google chrome by default output is plain text so you have explicitly provide output as html then it will work.
I think it will work.